# How to implement a Geo Code Filter of the USA when retrieving Tweets via the TwitteR package in R

Tags: r, twitter, filter, geocode

I want only want to retrieve Tweets from the USA via `TwitteR` package in R. In the explanation of the `SearchTwitteR` function it only says:

> For the geocode argument, the values are given in the format latitude,longitude,radius, where the radius can have either mi (miles) or km (kilometers) as a unit. For example `geocode='37.781157,-122.39720,1mi'.`"

But I don't want to filter from a specific place withing a radius, I want the whole country, the USA. 
Does anyone have a good advice for me?

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question, but if you have a list of latitudes and longitudes and need to determine if they are in a given area then this should help.

This similiar problem was answered here: [Checking if Longtitude/Latitude within Greater Toronto Area in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43243431/checking-if-longtitude-latitude-within-greater-toronto-area-in-r)

Instead of geocode, the `rgdal` and `sp` package can map a point and test if it is within a given shape file.  For the US the Census Bureau at: https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_nation.html

```
#dataframe of the points to test.
myTestDF <- data.frame(MyDate = c("USA", "Canada"),
                       latitude = c(37.781157, 43.8292),
                       longitude = c(-122.39720, -79.6563))


#Load the required library
library(rgdal)
#Download shape file from open data site and unzip contents into the working directory 
#Read the shape file
USA<- readOGR(".", "cb_2016_us_nation_20m")

myTestPoints <- myTestDF

coordinates(myTestPoints) <-  ~ longitude + latitude
proj4string(myTestPoints) <- proj4string(USA)

#over test to see if myTestPoints in the USA shapefile
cbind(myTestDF, over(myTestPoints, USA))
```