# Merge a dataframe with longitude and latitude and a shape file

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sp

I have a data frame that have information about crimes (variable x), and latitude and longitude of where that crime happened.
I have a shape file with the districts from são paulo city. 
I need to merge this two data, so i can have the number os crimes per districts. Is there a way to do this? I transformed my data frame in spatial data frame using

```
df.sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(cbind(df$longitude,df$latitude ), df)
```

but i dont know how to implemente this kind of merge to get what I need. On df I have more than 10 thousand obs like:

```
    latitude  longitude  n_homdol
1    -23.6     -46.6     1
2    -23.6     -46.6     1
3    -23.6     -46.6     1
4    -23.6     -46.6     1
5    -23.6     -46.6     1
6    -23.6     -46.6     1
```

The shape file is as follow:

```
                       geometry      NOME_DIST
1 POLYGON ((352436.9 7394174,... JOSE BONIFACIO
2 POLYGON ((320696.6 7383620,...    JD SAO LUIS
3 POLYGON ((349461.3 7397765,...    ARTUR ALVIM
4 POLYGON ((320731.1 7400615,...        JAGUARA
5 POLYGON ((338651 7392203, 3...  VILA PRUDENTE
6 POLYGON ((320606.2 7394439,...        JAGUARE
```

I need the sum of n_homdol by districts. I'm trying to merge the two data frames, but had no success.

Comment: Could you add what your data sets look like? Use `dput` or simply copy-paste what their `head` looks like to the **question.**

Comment: This is the classic 'point in polygon' problem. Also called a geospatial join. Check this out.  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sp/versions/1.3-1/topics/point.in.polygon

Comment: Could be similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43243431/checking-if-longitude-latitude-within-greater-toronto-area-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to switch from `sp` to the `sf`-package you'll have an easy way to do a spatial join with `dplyr`-like syntax.: `st_join`.

It would work like this (I have no R at this computer so there might be some "slips of the pen")

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

#Instead of data.frame of class "sp", create "simple features"-data.frame 

sf_df = st_as_sf(df, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)

#You'll have to convert your shapefile to sf, too. 
#Depending what class it is you can use "st_as_sf()"


#Then join the shapefile with sf_df via the "st_contains" which merges two rows 
#if a point from sf_df falls within a polygon from the shapefile.

shape_df <- st_join(shapefile, sf_df , join = st_contains)
```

You can then do:

```
shape_df %>%
group_by(NOME_DIST) %>%
summarise(crime = sum(n_homdol))
```

If you'd like to stick with `sp` I recommend looking at the answers in Dave2e's link in the comments.

Comment: Thanks! But when i use the st_contains, it gives me the following: Error in st_geos_binop("contains", x, y, sparse = sparse, prepared = prepared) : 
  st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE

Comment: Information about the shape file: Simple feature collection with 96 features and 9 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 313434.8 ymin: 7343789 xmax: 360663.2 ymax: 7416202
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    +proj=utm +zone=23 +south +ellps=aust_SA +units=m +no_defs

Comment: Your two data.frames have different projections. You have to transform either to the projection of the other using `st_transform()`. You can check out each projection via `st_crs()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56077248/poly2nb-function-takes-too-much-time-to-be-computed