# poly2nb function takes too much time to be computed

Tags: r, polygon, spatial

I have a data frame that have information about crimes (variable x), and latitude and longitude of where that crime happened. I have a shape file with the districts from são paulo city. That is df:

```
 latitude  longitude  n_homdol
    1    -23.6     -46.6     1
    2    -23.6     -46.6     1
    3    -23.6     -46.6     1
    4    -23.6     -46.6     1
    5    -23.6     -46.6     1
    6    -23.6     -46.6     1
```

And a shape file for the districts of são paulo,sp.dist.sf :

```
                      geometry      NOME_DIST
1 POLYGON ((352436.9 7394174,... JOSE BONIFACIO
2 POLYGON ((320696.6 7383620,...    JD SAO LUIS
3 POLYGON ((349461.3 7397765,...    ARTUR ALVIM
4 POLYGON ((320731.1 7400615,...        JAGUARA
5 POLYGON ((338651 7392203, 3...  VILA PRUDENTE
6 POLYGON ((320606.2 7394439,...        JAGUARE
```

With the help of @Humpelstielzchen, i join both data doing:

```
sf_df = st_as_sf(df, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)
shape_df<-st_join(sp.dist.sf, sf_df, join=st_contains)
```

My final goal is to implement a local moran i statistic, and i'm trying to do this with:

```
   sp_viz <- poly2nb(shape_df, row.names = shape_df$NOME_DIST)
    xy <- st_coordinates(shape_df)
    ww <- nb2listw(sp_viz, style ='W', zero.policy = TRUE)
    shape_df[is.na(shape_df)] <- 0
    locMoran <- localmoran(shape_df$n_homdol, ww)
sids.shade <- auto.shading(c(locMoran[,1],-locMoran[,1]),
                           cols=brewer.pal(5,"PRGn"))
    choropleth(shape_df, locMoran[,1], shading=sids.shade)
    choro.legend(-46.5, -20, sids.shade,fmt="%6.2f")
    title("Criminalidade (Local Moran's I)",cex.main=2)
```

But when i run the code, it takes hours to compute:

```
 sp_viz <- poly2nb(shape_df, row.names = shape_df$NOME_DIST)
```

I have 15,000 observations, for 93 districts. I tried to run the above code with only 100 observations, and it was fast and everything went right. But with the 15,000 obs i did not see the result, because de computation goes on forever. What may be happening? I am doing something wrong? Is there a better way to do this Local moran I test?

Answer (score 0):

As I can't just comment, here is some questions one might ask: 
 - how long do you mean by fast? some of my scripts run in seconds and I call it slow.
 - are all your observation identically structured? maybe the `poly2nb()` function is infinitely looping on an item which has an uncommon structure. You can use the `unique()` function to ensure this point.
 - Did you try to cut your dataset into pieces and to run each piece separately? this would help to see 1/ whether one of your parts has something to be corrected and 2/ whether R is loading all data at the same time, overloading the memory of your computer. Beware, this happen really often with huge datasets in R (and by huge, I mean data tables of > 50 Mo wheight).

Glad to have tried to help you, do not hesitate to question my answer !

Comment: Thanks for your help. By fast i mean fez seconds. By slow i mean more than 2 hours. How can i implement the function unique()? I will try to split the data in pieces.

Comment: `unique()`is contained in the `{base}` package, you do not need any installation ;)