# How to find if coordinates are in boundries of polygon

Tags: r, coordinates, distinct, polygon, kml

I have KML files of distinct's of my city. I imported them as list. I also have thousands of rentals and their coordinates. I need to find distinct's for each rental.

My Kml file has a lot of data in it.

Here is some part of my KML file. I don't know If that helps.

```
[[1]]
An object of class "Polygons"
Slot "Polygons":
[[1]]
An object of class "Polygon"
Slot "labpt":
[1] 29.30587 40.83289

Slot "area":
[1] 0.001922316

Slot "hole":
[1] FALSE

Slot "ringDir":
[1] 1

Slot "coords":
           [,1]     [,2]
  [1,] 29.28760 40.85329
  [2,] 29.28632 40.85438
  [3,] 29.28676 40.85450
  [4,] 29.28742 40.85476
  [5,] 29.28795 40.85551
  [6,] 29.28846 40.85611
  [7,] 29.28838 40.85693
```

Thank you,

Comment: This isn't something we can read into R to work with. Maybe you can construct an example using sample data that ships with one of the spatial packages

Comment: Maybe this question/answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43243431/checking-if-longitude-latitude-within-greater-toronto-area-in-r